# OpenJPA dao unit test crash - presistenceException: null

Tags: persistence, openjpa

I have created entities in my project. I have updated persistence.xml accordingly, HOWEVER when I run the build process all my DAO unit tests fail. We are using openjpa 2.3.0 and we suspect that there are missing types within persistence.xml .

```
 <openjpa-2.3.0-nonfinal-1540826-r422266:1542644 fatal general error>     org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ClassRedefiner.redefineClasses(ClassRedefiner.java:96)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.prepareUnenhancedClasses(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:176)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.loadPersistentTypes(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:312)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:236)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManagerRegistry.getEntityManager(JtaEntityManagerRegistry.java:115)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.getEntityManager(JtaEntityManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.persist(JtaEntityManager.java:137)
    at com.ngsoft.im.dao.impl.mssql.CallDaoImpl.addCall(CallDaoImpl.java:63)
    at com.ngsoft.im.dao.impl.mssql.CallDaoImpl.addCall(CallDaoImpl.java:18)
    at com.ngsoft.im.dao.CallDaoImplTest$2.execute(CallDaoImplTest.java:85)
    at com.ngsoft.im.dao.CallDaoImplTest$2.execute(CallDaoImplTest.java:81)
    at com.ngsoft.im.dao.access.DBAccessMethodWrite.accessDB(DBAccessMethodWrite.java:44)
    at com.ngsoft.im.dao.CallDaoImplTest.testAddAndGetCall(CallDaoImplTest.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ClassRedefiner.redefineClasses(ClassRedefiner.java:85)
    ... 61 more
   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
    ... 66 more
```

How can I get a better indication of what got wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you're seeing is due to OpenJPA trying to enhance your Entities. I suspect it might be somehow related to the JVM that you're using.

For whatever horrible reason OpenEJB decided to enable `openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses`, even through it is a horribly buggy feature. My recommendation is to set the property `openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses=unsupported` and configure the OpenEJB -javaagent.